# Neat way to have javascript function return status based on PHP variable?

Tags: php, javascript, oop, status

In a CMS I'm building I want to have my own javascript namespaced object `$cms`. This object should have a method/function `hasIdentity` that returns the status of whether the user is logged in.

Is there a way that I can have this method/function return the status without having to resort to either:

- AJAX
- a global var
- or rewriting the following script from within PHP

This is what I have so var:

```
var $cms = {
    hasIdentity: function()
    {
        return /* the status provided by PHP */;
    }
};
```

It's a bit of a esthetic matter perhaps, but I don't want to resort to this:

```
// write this global var;
var $isLoggedIn = false;

var $cms = {
    hasIdentity: function()
    {
        return $isLoggedIn;
    }
};
```

Or this:

```
var $cms = {
    hasIdentity: function()
    {
        $isLoggedIn = this.do.some.ajax.call();
        return $isLoggedIn;
    }
};
```

I was maybe thinking more of a sort of OOP approach, something like constructing the `$cms` object by writing it from within PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $cms = new $cms( <?php echo $loggedIn ? 'true', 'false' ?> );
</script>
```

Now, I believe I can't use the `new` keyword like that in Javascript, but I hope you catch my drift, and see where I want to go with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do:

```
$cms.isLoggedIn = <?php echo $loggedIn ? 'true', 'false' ?>;
```

That because your $cms object is not a constructor function. If it were, you would have been able to `new` it.

```
var CMS = function (loggedIn) {
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
};

CMS.prototype.hasIdentity = function () {
    return this.loggedIn;
};

$cms = new CMS(<?php echo $loggedIn ? 'true', 'false' ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie. Set it from the PHP when user logs in and have the `hasIdentity` method read the cookie and return it's state. It's not the safest solution since cookies can be forged, but you're checking everything on the server side too anyway, right? :)